# Animating divs to act as pages in CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to get content to move across the screen but I was having trouble moving text with Bootstrap's carousel.

I have an animation working, but the divs sit on top of each other so they animate in and out of their own positions, not in and out of the same position.

Here's the CSS

```
/* Home and about pages */
#about-page {
    transform: translateX(200%);
}

.slideOutLeft {
    animation: slideOutLeft 1s forwards;
}
.slideInLeft {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    animation: slideInLeft 1s forwards;
}
.slideOutRight{
    transform: translateX(200%);
    animation: slideOutRight 1s forwards;
}
.slideInRight {
    animation: slideInRight 1s forwards;
}

/* Slide in from the left */
@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-200%); }
}
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% { transform: translateX(-200%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}
@keyframes slideOutRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(200%); }
}
@keyframes slideInRight {
    0% { transform: translateX(200%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}
```

which is triggered by the following JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    // Go to home
    $("#home-link").click(function(){
        // Link appearance
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#about-link').removeClass('active');

        // Slide in homepage
        $('#home-page').removeClass('slideOutLeft');
        $('#home-page').addClass('slideInLeft');
        // Slide out about page
        $('#about-page').removeClass('slideInRight');
        $('#about-page').addClass('slideOutRight');
        $('#about-page').addClass('hidden');

    });

    // Go to about slide
    $("#about-link").click(function(){
        // Link appearance
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#home-link').removeClass('active');

        // Slide out homepage
        $('#home-page').removeClass('slideInLeft');
        $('#home-page').addClass('slideOutLeft');
        $('#home-page').addClass('hidden');
        // Slide in about page
        $('#about-page').removeClass('slideOutRight');
        $('#about-page').addClass('slideInRight');
    });

});
```

You can see the problem at testing version of the site [here](http://7sqn.moreland.nz/).

Thanks for all of your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a class item in your page containers

```
<div class="inner cover">
  <div id="home-page" class="item">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>

  <div id="about-page" class="item">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this block in your css

```
.inner.cover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```